# Reducer not completing and getting stuck at 99%

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I am having some issues with running a mapreduce job. The mapper completes quickly. However, the reducer gets stuck at 99.33 %. I could see some IO errors in the log. However, isn't hadoop itself supposed to handle the IO errors. I ran the job twice and the same thing. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

How balanced are your keys ? It sounds like one key has the bulk of your records, so they can only be processed by a single reducer.

If your job is some calculation which can be divided easily into sub-calculations ( like simple counts), try breaking up your job into two jobs by salting your key.  Add a random number or string to your key, in order to distribute to multiple reducers on the first pass, then merge those results on a second pass.

Hope that makes sense !!!

Answer (score 0):

Please provide some more input

1. What kind of setup do you have, is it pseudo cluster with one VM or with multiple VMs
2. Run `df` on your system as you get the IO Exception , to confirm that you don't have a disk space issue.
3. What do you mean by "it is getting stuck"...Reducers will timeout and fail at the end. So please elaborate what you mentioned.
4. Answer to your questions `However, isn't hadoop itself supposed to handle the IO errors.`
   Yes, like any good code, Hadoop handles IOException, but it may or may not finish job successfully after the IO error depending on your answer to my question 1 & ,2. Simply, put hadoop can be fault tolerant, if you provide enough redundancy. If you have less redundancy, hadoop jobs will fail on serious issues like IOException.